# How to implement slideout menu using uiviewcontroller.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

> Hi all i am working on slide out menu in my app. i present a viewcontroller using the following on mainviewcontroller.

```
- (IBAction)MenuButton:(id)sender {


 tlc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlideOut"];
[tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-800, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self addChildViewController:tlc];
[self.view addSubview:tlc.view];
[tlc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-800, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureLeftAction:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
}];

}
```

> i need to open and hide view using UIGesturerecogniton, so i use the following code, by this code i am able to present view but i am not able to hide it using gesture recognition. please look at my code.

```
-(void)SwipGestureAction {
NSLog(@"gesture");
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureRightAction:)];
swiperight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
   }


-(void)SwipGestureRightAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight {

NSLog(@"left");

tlc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlideOut"];
[tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-800, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self addChildViewController:tlc];
[self.view addSubview:tlc.view];
[tlc didMoveToParentViewController:self];


                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                         [tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-800, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

                         swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureLeftAction:)];
                         swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
                         [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

                     }];



 }


  -(void)SwipGestureLeftAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight {

                     NSLog(@"right");



                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                         [tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-800, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                         [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
                         }];




}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use some library like https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController or find another one, if that is acceptable.

Comment: no i am not using any library

Comment: See this link, https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController use this framework

Comment: @lyyappan Ravi thats not working in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that same issue before some days ago bro;

I have solve that issue by using following **tutorial** .

that is perfect answer for me... I hope that is also helpful for you..:)

https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

and

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: try to use SWRevealViewController... I;m suru.. you will not face the single issue with that.. :)

Comment: if i use SWRevealViewController it will push the main view, but i want to open slide menu on top of main

Comment: check your answer is here bro.....   https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/312

Comment: glad.. I could help you.. you can upvote this answer..:)